# Should “Move this discussion to chat” be "Add a chat to post"?

Tags: feature-request

Often when I have an extended discussion with someone regarding a question, the "Move this discussion to chat" appears, and I automatically think "Oh no, not chat. I don't want to go there."

Wondering if I'm the only one that thinks like that?

I think this comes from the fact that *I am being **forced** to leave the current page.*

Wouldn't it be more user-friendly to have the chat box appear for a **temporary amount** of time beside the question for extended discussions?

It would insight more people to follow the live discussion, especially on popular questions that get a lot of comments?

Also from a third person point of view, when I see two people having an extended discussion and then have the "Move to this discussion to chat" link appear and I click it, only to find no one in chat and no one talking... I often think "Why did I click to leave the page?"

Comment: I think the main point of *moving it to another page* is that it declutters the main question page. If you want to talk, go ahead, just *do it elsewhere*.

Comment: No, you're not the only one that thinks that. I think exactly the same thing. Sometimes, I accidentally click the link (it happens more often than you think), and I freak out and look for an "undo" button. (There isn't one, but you can just delete the comment it auto-posts.) Changing the wording isn't going to change anything. What it's trying to say is "stop having a live discussion; this isn't the place for that." I would be very against *further* integrating chat with a Q&A site.

Comment: @CodyGray I see your point. I can see how live chat on a Q&A site is not good, but sometimes it's required to get more information from the OP. Changing pages has plenty of downsides (notably where we go away from the information rich post the OP made). I've noticed that deleting my previous comments removes the "Move this discussion to chat". I can then continue the "live discussion" in the comments as long as I delete previous comments and update my post accordingly with the new information from the comments. It's a tiring work around, but it avoids going to a different page.

Comment: If it is required to get more information from the OP, then the question should be closed until that information is provided. You can then leave as many comments as you want and flag them for deletion once the question has been edited.